# How to open safari using XCTest

Tags: objective-c, xctest

I am new to XCTest,I am trying to safari app in my iPhone using XCTest but not able to do anything as such is there in way to achieve this

Code tried as of now :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.ggogle.com"]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to open safari using XCTest. I have tried the following, it gives error "App accessibility isn't loaded".

Declare the XCUIApplication private methods interface in Brigding-Header.h:

```
@interface XCUIApplication (Private)
- (id)initPrivateWithPath:(NSString *)path bundleID:(NSString *)bundleID;
- (void)resolve;
@end
```

Then try to open safari:

```
let safari : XCUIApplication = XCUIApplication(privateWithPath: nil, bundleID: "com.apple.safari")
safari.launch();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com"];

if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url]) {
NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open url:",[url description]);
}
```

Comment: Tried it but not working :(.., It is saying failed to open url

Comment: The above code is it for XCTest only ? or is there something which i am missing like importing some library or method type

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amSApTmxqrc .Open this It will be helpful to you :)

Comment: I have seen this video, it is very basic and is not showing anything about opening safari app and passing any url using XCTest :(

Comment: is your url is correct? because this code is working in my project.

Comment: method name can be anything ? return type can be void ?

Comment: 2016-11-28 18:48:17.674811 XCTRunner[823:90040] Failed to open url:http://www.google.com

Answer (score 0):

Write an unit test that mocks `[UIApplication openURL:]` and verify that you are passing a correct URL to it. Or if you want the other direction, write a unit test that will call `UIApplicationDelegate` methods in the called order, simulating opening a link by your app. This is as far you can go with XCUnit. And test manually.

**or try this**

```
NSString *filePath = [[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YourFileName.json"];
XCTAssertNotNil(filePath);
```